# heroku pgbackups:url command is no longer working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, heroku

How do I download my dump directly from Amazon AWS S3 if `heroku pgbackups:url b004` isn't working?

Specifically, when I run this command it returns:

```
 !    Please add the pgbackups addon first via:
 !    heroku addons:add pgbackups
```

And then when I run this command I get:

```
 !    No such add-on plan.
```

What to do? I'd like to get the link/URL to my pgdump file b004, and then use that link to import the postgresql data onto my mirrored heroku app.. But I am having trouble getting the URL, which used to be easily done by running `heroku pgbackups:url b004`

Any help here would be great!

Comment: Just going to leave this here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download backup b004 use the following syntax:

```
curl -o b004.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url b004`
```

That will download the backup as b004.dump in the current directory.

Comment: But how do I get the amazon s3 URL, to the actual dump.. that way I can just run something like heroku pg:backups restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump' DATABASE_URL

Comment: The `heroku pg:backups public-url b004` part of that command is what returns the URL